# GOCD agent registration with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, go-cd

I want register kubernetes-elastic-agents with gocd-server. In the doc https://github.com/gocd/kubernetes-elastic-agents/blob/master/install.md

I need kubernetes security token and cluster ca certificate. My Kubernetes is running. How do I create a security token? Where can I find the cluster ca cert?

Jake

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers:

The first is that it's very weird that one would need to manually input those things since they live in a well-known location on disk of any Pod (that isn't excluded via the `automountServiceAccountToken` field) as described in [Accessing the API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)

The second is that if you really do need a statically provisioned token belonging to a `ServiceAccount`, then you can either retrieve an existing token from the `Secret` that is created by default for every `ServiceAccount`, or create a second `Secret` as described in [Manually create a service account API token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-service-account-api-token)

The CA cert you requested is present in every Pod in the cluster at the location mentioned in the first link, as well as in the `~/.kube/config` of anyone who wishes to access the cluster. `kubectl config view -o yaml` will show it to you.